# How to get two arrays out of one csv file in Python?

Tags: python, list, csv

I've a csv file containing lines like this:

- A,x1
- A,x2
- A,x3
- B,x4
- B,x5
- B,x6

*The first part reflects the group (A or B) a value (x1, x2, ...) belongs to.*

What I want to do now is importing that csv file in Python, so I have two lists in the end:

- ListA = [x1, x2, x3]
- ListB = [x4, x5, x6]

Can someone help me out with that? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use one of the many existing python CSV import tools, then write a bit of code to process the data after it's extracted into your specific format.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

file_path = "path_to_your_csv"

stream_in = open(file_path, 'rb')

A = [];
B = [];

for line in stream_in.readlines():
    add_to_List = line.split(",")[1].strip()

    if 'A' in line:
        A.append(add_to_List);
    if 'B' in line:
        B.append(add_to_List)
stream_in.close()
print A
print B
```

Answer (score 0):

after putting your data in a pandas Series object names ser, just type in `ser.loc("A")`
and `ser.loc("B")` to get the data slice you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using preassigned names for your vectors lead to lots of duplicated logic, that gets more and more complicated if you add new vectors to your data description...

It's much better to use *dictionaries*

```
data=[['a', 12.3], ['a', 12.4], ['b', 0.4], ['c', 1.2]]

vectors = {}  # an empty dictionary
for key, value in data:
     vectors.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

The relevant docs, from [the python official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html)

> setdefault(key[, default])
>
> ```
>      If key is in the dictionary, return its value.
>      If not, insert key with a value of default and return default.
>      default defaults to None.
> ```
>
> append(x)
>
> ```
>      appends x to the end of the sequence (same as s[len(s):len(s)] = [x])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
In[1]: import pandas as pd

In[2]: df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header=None)

In[3]: print(df)

out[3]:
```

```
       0   1
    0  A  x1
    1  A  x2
    2  A  x3
    3  B  x4
    4  B  x5
```

```
In[4]: ListA = df[0].tolist()
In[5]: print(ListB)
Out[5]: ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']

In[6]: ListB = t_df[1].tolist()
In[7]: print(ListB)
Out[7]: ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6']
```